# How to look through key/value pairs in object for specific key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm brand new to Javascript and just learning the basics.  Say that I have an array representing the names of cards in a deck like this:

```
var deckNames = [
  "sA", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", "s7", "s8", "s9", "s10", "sJ", "sQ", "sK",
  "hA", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8", "h9", "h10", "hJ", "hQ", "hK",
  "cA", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8", "c9", "c10", "cJ", "cQ", "cK",
  "dA", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7", "d8", "d9", "d10", "dJ", "dQ", "dK",
  ];
```

along with an Object with the values of each card in the deck like this:

```
var deckValues = {
  sA: 11, s2: 2, s3: 3, s4: 4, s5: 5, s6: 6, s7: 7, s8: 8, s9: 9, s10: 10, sJ: 10, sQ: 10, sK: 10,
  hA: 11, h2: 2, h3: 3, h4: 4, h5: 5, h6: 6, h7: 7, h8: 8, h9: 9, h10: 10, hJ: 10, hQ: 10, hK: 10,
  cA: 11, c2: 2, c3: 3, c4: 4, c5: 5, c6: 6, c7: 7, c8: 8, c9: 9, c10: 10, cJ: 10, cQ: 10, cK: 10,
  dA: 11, d2: 2, d3: 3, d4: 4, d5: 5, d6: 6, d7: 7, d8: 8, d9: 9, d10: 10, dJ: 10, dQ: 10, dK: 10,
};
```

I've written a "deal" function that randomly selects a card from the "deckNames" array.  I have two questions:

1. I am trying to write a function that can go through the "deckValues" object and return the value it finds.  How would I go about looking in the "deckValues" object to find the name of the card that was dealt and then return that associated value?
2. Am I being redundant by having an array just for the names and having an Object that has the names already with the values associated with them?

Comment: just use `deckValues["s8"]` . I mean, you may get prop vith `obj["string"]`

Comment: It appears you've forgotten to show [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), which makes this [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deckValues properties can be accessed by name in two ways:

```
var storeValue = deckValues.sA;
var storeValue = deckValues['sA'];
```

So to look at the values using your deckNames array you could do this:

```
var storeValue = deckValues[deckNames[0]];
```

You could easily place the above statement in a loop and replace the 0 with a variable that iterates with the loop.

You don't really need to have an array and an object you can loop through object properties.

```
for(var name in deckValues) {
    var storeValue = deckValues[name];
    console.log('Deck name is ' + name + ' and the value is ' + storeValue);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
console.log(deckValues["sA"]);
```

which will log the value "11", and so forth.

Yes, likely you can do away with the deckNames.

Answer (score 1):

The automate version.

```js
var deckNames = [
  "sA", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", "s7", "s8", "s9", "s10", "sJ", "sQ", "sK",
  "hA", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8", "h9", "h10", "hJ", "hQ", "hK",
  "cA", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8", "c9", "c10", "cJ", "cQ", "cK",
  "dA", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7", "d8", "d9", "d10", "dJ", "dQ", "dK"
  ];
  
var deckValues = {
  sA: 11, s2: 2, s3: 3, s4: 4, s5: 5, s6: 6, s7: 7, s8: 8, s9: 9, s10: 10, sJ: 10, sQ: 10, sK: 10,
  hA: 11, h2: 2, h3: 3, h4: 4, h5: 5, h6: 6, h7: 7, h8: 8, h9: 9, h10: 10, hJ: 10, hQ: 10, hK: 10,
  cA: 11, c2: 2, c3: 3, c4: 4, c5: 5, c6: 6, c7: 7, c8: 8, c9: 9, c10: 10, cJ: 10, cQ: 10, cK: 10,
  dA: 11, d2: 2, d3: 3, d4: 4, d5: 5, d6: 6, d7: 7, d8: 8, d9: 9, d10: 10, dJ: 10, dQ: 10, dK: 10
};

var givenKey = 'c6'; //you can change this 
var result;

for (var key in deckValues) {
 if (key == givenKey) {
  result = deckValues[key];
  }
}

console.log(result);
```